# WP Как поставить ссылку на главную страницу текущего мультиязычного сайта?

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

Есть некий мультиязычный сайт `https://example.net/` у него для логотипа задана ссылка на главную страницу

```
<a class="header_logo" href="<?php echo site_url('') ?>"><img class="header_logo__img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/logo.svg" width="150" height="30" alt="logo"></a>
```

Как переделать код для href данной ссылки, что бы если пользователь находиться на страницах португальской версии сайта, при клике на эту ссылку его вело на
`https://example.net/pt/` на французских версиях сайта на `https://example.net/fr/` ? Есть ли какое просто решение возможно уже вшитое в систему, или надо постоянно узнавать lang а там производить if/else ? (Использую [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) плагин)

Comment: [pll_home_url(  $lang = '' );](http://hookr.io/functions/pll_home_url/) не пробовали? Параметром можете передать текущий language code используя `pll_current_language()`.

Comment: Да, спасибо ` href="<?php echo  pll_home_url( pll_current_language() ); ?> ` отрабатывает